# update a table from the same table. Relation between records in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with records like this called `garanzie_row`:

```
id_cred         id_gar
CD000001440     CD000001068
```

CD000001440 and CD000001068 are defined in another table and each of them has a status.
this table is named `crediti`

```
id_cre          STATUS
CD000001440   open
CD000001068
```

What I'd like to do is to iterate all the records in the records in the first table and set in the second table the status for each CRED B as the status of the corresponding CRED A

but I can't find a single query to do the select and the update in one piece (obviously in steps it works easily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with `update` and `join`s:

```
update crediti cb join
       garanzie_row gr
       on cb.cred = gr.credb join
       crediti ca
       on ca.cred = gr.creda
    set cb.status = ca.status;
```

Comment: so you are selecting the second table two times. The first time you call it sb and you select the cred to be updated. The second time you select with sa the record containg the status to be copied. Am I right?

Comment: I jsut miss one point: you are speaking about sb.credb and sa.creda but these are fields of the first table... Can you check the query? I have updated the question with the real names. The goal is to have CD000001068 with status open in the second table because CD000001440 has the same status and the two are connected in the first table

Comment: @LelioFaieta took me a 'second' at 'first' (pun intended) but this is what it would look like for you  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/38957